# Express and WebSocket listening on the same port

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have an app.js which is used to trigger two events when some POST data are received:

1. Insert POST data into a database
2. Send a message to a client using a WebSocket

Here is the **app.js** (only the important lines)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = require('./server');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.post('/server', server);

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Slack bot listening');
});
```

And here is the **server.js** (only the important lines)

```
var db = require('./DB');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var insertData = function(req, res){

    var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
    console.log('WebSocketServer created');
    wss.on('connection', function(wss){
        wss.send(JSON.stringify('Socket open'));
    });
    wss.on('close', function(){
        console.log('WebServerSocket has been closed');
    });
};

module.exports = insertData;
```

What I would like to achieve is to set the WebSocketServer in a way that it listen to the same port of the app. 
I thought about passing the *server* var from **app.js** to **server.js** but

1. I think this a not an elegant way to do it
2. I don't know how to do it

What do you guys think?

Comment: You skipped some lines. You did not `mount` the websocket server on express app?

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question. It's the usual way, why is it not elegant? Require(something); myServer.mount(something); module like any other.

Comment: I indeed not mounted the WebSocketServer on the express app because I do not know how to do it. Would you be kind enough to provide an example? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Based on your code and comments, here's a super simple example of how it would work together.

First, the **`http-server.js`** - a typical express app, except that we do not start the server with `app.listen()`:

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Let's create the regular HTTP request and response
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  console.log('Get index');
  fs.createReadStream('./index.html')
  .pipe(res);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  let message = req.body.message;
  console.log('Regular POST message: ', message);
  return res.json({

    answer: 42
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Now, the **`ws-server.js`** example, where we create the WSS server from a node native `http.createServer()`. Now, note that this is where we import the app, and give this native http.createServer the app instance to use.

Start the app with `PORT=8080 node ws-server.js` :

(***Note*** you're launching the second, socket related, file (ws-server) not the first, http related, file (http-server).)

```
'use strict';

let WSServer = require('ws').Server;
let server = require('http').createServer();
let app = require('./http-server');

// Create web socket server on top of a regular http server
let wss = new WSServer({

  server: server
});

// Also mount the app here
server.on('request', app);

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
 
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    
    console.log(`received: ${message}`);
    
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({

      answer: 42
    }));
  });
});


server.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {

  console.log(`http/ws server listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Finally, this sample **`index.html`** will work by creating both a POST and a Socket "request" and display the response:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>WS example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Socket message response: </h2>
  <pre id="response"></pre>
  <hr/>
  <h2>POST message response: </h2>
  <pre id="post-response"></pre>
  <script>

  // Extremely simplified here, no error handling or anything
document.body.onload = function() {

    'use strict';

  // First the socket requesta
  function socketExample() {
    console.log('Creating socket');
    let socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/');
    socket.onopen = function() {

      console.log('Socket open.');
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({message: 'What is the meaning of life, the universe and everything?'}));
      console.log('Message sent.')
    };
    socket.onmessage = function(message) {

      console.log('Socket server message', message);
      let data = JSON.parse(message.data);
      document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    };
  }

  // Now the simple POST demo
  function postExample() {

    console.log('Creating regular POST message');
  
    fetch('/', {  
      method: 'post',  
      headers: {  
        "Content-type": "application/json"  
      },  
      body: JSON.stringify({message: 'What is the meaning of post-life, the universe and everything?'})  
    })
    .then(response => response.json())  
    .then(function (data) {  
    
      console.log('POST response:', data);
      document.getElementById('post-response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);   
    })  
    .catch(function (error) {  
      console.log('Request failed', error);  
    });   
  }

  // Call them both;

  socketExample();
  postExample();
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note you'll need a quite recent browser, one that has both WebSocket and fetch APIs for this client side part, but it's irrelevant anyway, it just gives you the gist of it.

Comment: Waow @Zlatko, that is one hell of an answer. Thanks a lot for the time you took for me. Much appreciated! Works perfectly.

Comment: @Zlatko Can't set up the nearly equivalent using nodejs 'net' instead of 'ws'.  net.createServer does not take a instance of the http server like instantiating a new ws instance does -  new WSServer({server: server});

Comment: @DKebler the answer here was specific to `express.js` and `ws` module, as in the question. Are you trying to wrap a `net` listener around express? What for, how exactly? Do you have a question related?

Comment: was trying to limit dependencies on a RPi, but ```net``` socket/server I have discovered has no built in connection upgrade code for establishing communication with websocket client so ... will use ```ws``` or the like.

Comment: I see this answer is old but is't there a glaring problem that the post would fail because the server is listening on 8080 not 80. And I don't see a port specified in that fetch. Unless you are using a revers proxy. This solution will fail miserably.

Comment: Well, I don't think it will fail miserably. For one, the request url refers to a relative path, and since you served the file from the same origin (localhost:8080 in this case), the post will follow there too. And the websocket connects there too, as well. For two, this is stackoverflow, and the solution is not meant to be taken literally, merely as a proof of concept. It would  . I seriously hope you do not blindly copy code from here to your work, without reading it, understanding it and then adapting your code. For three, yes, you'd certainly use reverse proxy. You worry too much ;)

Comment: Hah I have a feeling this won't work for my desired setup of http server + custom websocket handler + webpack-dev-middleware all from the same port.

Comment: The way I realized I can solve my use-case is to use webpack-dev-middleware as an express middleware then instead of adding in webpack-hot-middleware I instead subscribe to webpack compiler events via compiler.hooks.afterEmit and then pass a message through the existing custom websocket server.

Comment: Oh, that's so nice of you! This answer keeps getting upvotes, I assume this is such a common question for people, good that it still helps. And you made a nice abstraction of the answer as well.

Comment: @Zlatko , on the contrary, thank YOU.  One of the greatest answers on the whole site.  Magnificent.  Thanks.

Comment: @Zlatko, thank you so much! Killed almost a day to solve this problem.

Comment: Good to know that answers still help, five years after I posted them :)

Answer (score 13):

## http and ws on the same port 80, "Amazing Zlatko Method™."

You'll have a file, say main.js, with

```
 var app = express()
```

and many lines of express code.

It is perfectly OK to have **as much middleware as you want in the usual way with no changes**.

```
var app = express()
app.use(session(session_options))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
// etc etc
app.get ...
app.get ...
app.post ...
app.post ...
```

Normally at the **end of that file** you would

```
 app.listen(80, (err) => { ... })
```

Delete that.

```
 //app.listen(80, (err) => { ... })
```

**No other changes** in the express app file.

In your websocket file, say multiplayer.js, you would normally have

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 9999,
    perMessageDeflate: false
})
```

In fact, change to

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
/*const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 2828,
    perMessageDeflate: false
});*/
let WSServer = WebSocket.Server;
let server = require('http').createServer();
let app = require('./main'); // note, that's your main.js file above
let wss = new WSServer({
  server: server,
  perMessageDeflate: false
})
server.on('request', app);
```

TBC, note that, surprisingly to me, WebSocket.Server does indeed naturally want to listen on 80.

And at the end of that file

```
server.listen(80, function() {
    console.log(`Amazing Zlatko Method™ combo server on 80`);
});
```

**Note!** - launch the 'multiplayer.js' file (**not** 'main.js').

It works perfectly. Amazing stuff.

Comment: Can this setup support http also?

Comment: its failing for me at the part "server.on('request', app); " since the passed app is no callback function but an object (as it is neither in your example). How did you get this to work?

Comment: @drecunion this answer has 7 (seven) highlighted code samples.    Did you do (4) and (7) ?

Comment: Im pretty sure i did exactly everything like in your example and followed every step. If you would be so kind, i have created a github gist with my code if you could have a look at it, it would be awesome! https://gist.github.com/Drecu/2330024344404807600054425efefa36

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are quite nice...
Please find the below sample code, seems a little simpler

```js
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
      var host = http.address().address
      var port = http.address().port
      console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
      console.log('Client connected to the WebSocket');

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
      });

      socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received a chat message");
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    })
```