# can I use webpack middlewares in vanilla node.js server?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I used `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware` before to run an express server in development. This approach can run a development environment without using `webpack dev server`. Webpack handles the bundling and express handles the server logic and static files.

Now I want to use vanilla node.js server because express setup is not fast enough for my app. And I want to use webpack with my new setup. But I wonder if I can use the previous two middlewares in my new setup? If I can that would be perfect. But if I can't what is the best approach for me? I have read something like starting two servers during development. One for webpack-dev-server and the other running node.js server. I think this approach is complicated and make me confused in development. Is there any better way? I personally prefer something like two configurations in my `server.js`, for example:

```
const isDeveloping = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const port = isDeveloping ? 8080 : process.env.PORT;
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.info('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

But I don't know how to move on, as I am more familiar with using the middlewares than fiddling with the configuration.

Comment: If your Express setup isn't fast enough, I doubt that a plain HTTP server will be much better (Express's layer on top of `http` is pretty thin). There's a standalone [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) that you could use, but that's also based on Express so it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @robertklep based on the test here [Performance 2017](https://raygun.com/blog/node-js-performance-2017/) the performance difference is obvious. I haven't done the test myself though but I want to squeeze as much power from Node.js as possible.

Comment: You're missing the point, though: the Webpack middlewares are intended to be used during development, not in production. Who cares if Express can "only" handle 2000 requests/second during development?

Comment: @robertklep yes webpack is used in development but what about express? It is only used in development? The test is not about webpack it is about using different frameworks or raw Node.

Comment: If you are worried that much about performance (seriously though, I've run websites that handled millions of requests a day using Express and it never felt like a bottleneck), you should split your app from Webpack anyway, because you want to be serving static files through a CDN and not through Node. So running a separate `webpack-dev-server` is probably what you want.

Comment: @robertklep thanks for the example. I am using websocket protocol not http requests. On average the server may send  6000+ messages per second. I am not sure if that would be somewhat equal to more than ten million requests a day. The test is based on requests per second but I don't know what is the equal term of request in websocket.

Comment: The benchmarks you linked to deal with HTTP requests, which is a lot different than websocket messages (which it doesn't benchmark at all). Also, both plain HTTP and Express don't handle websockets themselves, they offload it (to [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws), for instance).

Comment: @robertklep You mean in the app the express may not be in use except for loading the home page and static files? (It's only one page) I can't find any benchmark regarding using frameworks with `ws` module. But I guess using vanilla Node.js still has some advantages. I only use express  to serve the home page in production. Just don't know how big the impact would be.

Comment: Websocket connection requests are received by the HTTP server (whether that's plain HTTP or Express), but almost immediately handed off to the dedicated Websocket handler that `ws` provides. If you homepage only consists of static files, you might as well move it to a dedicated HTTP server like NGINX.

Comment: @robertklep I actually find a way to separate websocket server with http server in my app, using method in this [express and websocket server listening on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808925/express-and-websocket-listening-on-the-same-port) article. Therefore I can still use express server to serve static contents and homepage but offload everything else to a new vanilla Node.js server that serves as the websocket server. This way I don't need to worry about integrating webpack in my app.