# How to send ws message from route request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I've been trying to create an app that uses telegram-bot, express server and react app. Therefore, I need to create a POST request from telegram-bot to express, while express sends POST data to a websocket connection:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const expressWs = require("express-ws")(app);

// handles bot request
app.post("/request", (req, res) => {
  playlist.push(req.body.url);
  res.status(200).send({ message: "video is added to playlist" });
});

// after handling requst data must go here and send ws message to client side
app.ws("/echo", (ws, req) => {
  ws.on("message", msg => {
  ws.send(`msg is = ${msg}`);
  });
});
```

Am I making it right, and if so, how  to call ws.send from after handling request at app.post route?

Comment: There could be multiple clients connected to the `/echo` endpoint which has nothing to do with your `/request` endpoint. 

If what you are trying to do is broadcast the contents of the post request to the connected client, then you would have to watch for requests to the post endpoint and send that request to those clients.

You can use the ws package instead.

Answer (score 5):

From the understanding I have from your question, here is an updated version of your code that does exactly what you want.

I replaced the `express-ws` package with `ws` since that would be sufficient for your use case.

The express server runs on port 8080 while the websocket server runs on port 8081 since are different protocols and would not run on the same port (You can make it work but I do not recommend it [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808925/express-and-websocket-listening-on-the-same-port)

```
const express = require("express");
const Websocket = require('ws');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const wss = new Websocket.Server({ port: 8081 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('One client connected');
  ws.on("message", msg => {
    ws.send(`msg is = ${msg}`);
  });
})

// handles bot request
app.post("/request", (req, res) => {
  // Broadcast URL to connected ws clients
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    // Check that connect are open and still alive to avoid socket error
    if (client.readyState === Websocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(url);
    }
  });

  res.status(200).send({ message: "video is added to playlist" });
});


app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Express listening on 8080');
  console.log('Websocket on 8081');
});
```

Tested via curl with `curl -d 'url=https://example.com/examplesong' localhost:8080/request` I had a client connected to `ws://localhost:8081` and everything looks good.