# How to redirect react app to payment success page after completing payment by scanning a QR code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, graphql

I have a **PERN**(Postgres, Express, React, Node) e-commerce app. I want to notify a user that the payment is successful by **redirecting to a payment successful page** after a user **scans QR code** to pay.

However, I'm not sure how do I achieve this.

Currently, after the user completed a payment, I will receive a **REST's `POST`** request for payment confirmation from a bank API. . However, I'm also using GraphQL and I think that **Graphql's `Subscription`** could be what I'm trying to achieve.

**Does anyone know how am I supposed to achieve this?**

1. Are there anyways to send a request from REST to Graphql on my own server?
2. Or are there any better ways to do this?

[Just like what is done in this video:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-CiLrcwVbQ)

Comment: Do you handle the request on serverside when the user scans a `QR Code` ?

Comment: @SilvanBregy Yes. When the user scans QR Code, the bank send a post request to my serverside.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that you are looking for a way to notify your client that the payment was successful?

I assume you know how to handle redirect logic so here are the ways you can notify your web-app from the server.

### 1. Regular HTTP request

The client sends a regular HTTP-request to your server and you withhold the response until you received the 'payment completed' request from the bank API. If your request times out before the bank API confirms the payment - you simply send the same request again. This pattern is also known as [Long Polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/)

### 2. Server-Sent Events

Your client can open a channel to your server that allow your server to send Events to your client (one-way). It is fairly easy to implement and a solid way to handle one-way communication. Check out the MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

### 3. Web-Sockets [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

You are probably familiar with these since they are the de-facto standard nowadays. Similar to Server-Sent Events but they allow two-way communication.

Most libraries that handle client-server communication implement a combination of these technologies in order to provide a fallback solution. I would recommend to stick to one of these libraries as they handle many edge-cases that are otherwise work-intensive to cover.

As you pointed out, if you are already using GraphQL you can simply use its [subscriptions api](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/). It uses WebSockets with a fallback to long-polling underneath.

Other popular options include [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) or [graphql-sse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-sse).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using SSE but it didn't work. The problem is that the request sent from the Bank API after completion of the payment is `POST` request. Unfortunately, SSE only allows GET request. Therefore, the front end could not listen to the same route which made the update notification impossible. Do you recommend websocket instead? Would websocket work? This case is a bit complicated since it the update is from external API. I found this post which might work though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483487/how-to-send-ws-message-from-route-request. Unsure it will work

Comment: The webhook being called should be completely independent from the SSE evensource. A possible implementation could be to update your purchase data in you DB to 'payment verified' and the event source sends an event in response to this.

Comment: That sounds interesting. So it is possible to listen to the change in my database? I currently do update the database to payment verified but have no idea how to listen to that changes in the database.